# How does FFTW do in place transform?

Tags: fft, fftw

I'm using r2c and c2r in FFTW to do fast convolution, since IFFT(FFT(v1)*FFT(v2))=conv(v1,v2).
However, to save more RAM, I would like to use in_place_transform. This is supposed to replace the FFTW_ESTIMATE flag in

```
plan p = fftwf_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, in1, out1, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
```

however the complier doesn't recognize FFTW_IN_PLACE and says its undefined.

Doe anyone know how to do in place transform? Would this save RAM since only one array is used? (Or would FFTW actually allocate a temp array anyway, so this doesn't save space at all?)

Thank you!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm#Data_reordering.2C_bit_reversal.2C_and_in-place_algorithms

Comment: From the docs, in relation to upgrading from FFTW 2 to FFTW 3: "In-place transforms no longer interpret their output argument as scratch space, nor is there an FFTW_IN_PLACE flag. You simply pass the same pointer for both the input and output arguments."